# rotate to movement direction

Tags: java, 2d, libgdx

If I have a player character that can move 8-directionally, I can set the rotation of the player to face the direction of movement. But if I want to smoothly rotate to a direction, sometimes the player will take the "long way around" (i.e., player is at -90 degrees, facing right; I press S and it will rotate 270 degrees to be at 180 degrees, facing down). How can I fix this? I tried adding 360 to the desired angle until it was within 90 degrees, but that didn't work (probably just because I'm too tired, though). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: ? Not the same question

Comment: You need a proper getAngleDifference function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878907/the-smallest-difference-between-2-angles

Comment: @user55564 that link was actually really helpful, thanks!